# Can Service.onCreate be called before App.onCreate? [android]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

I have a simple Android process with a Service (a FirebaseMessagingService specifically) and a custom App class that extends Application.

Almost always App.onCreate() is called before Service.onCreate(), but I was surprised to find a run where the debug log showed that Service.onCreate() was called first, and in fact Service.onNewToken() too was called before App.onCreate().

This would cause my application to malfunction because it is the App that wires up various broadcast receivers and shared preferences listeners, and having the messaging token be received prior to this causes it to not be used correctly.

This happened once in my dev environment when I uninstalled the app and then re-ran it via Android studio.

Are there any official guarantees about App.onCreate() being called before any other services and activities? If so, how do I reconcile my observation?

Comment: can you check if the timestamp for the log is exactly same or not for both the onCreate. Basically, only ContentProviders can be initialized before Application not the activity or the service.

Comment: @RahulKumar sorry I should have copied/pasted the log. There were 2 log messages from the service that preceded log messages from App, so it is unlikely that both had exactly the same timestamps. Thanks for the confirmation that it doesn't sound right for service to be initialized first.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the log. From your previous comment, it seems that your log does not include timestamps. How do you know that those service-related log messages were not from an earlier execution of an app (one that had already called an `App.onCreate()`)?